# How to login to Ubuntu after first install?

Tags: dual-boot, login, password

I know this sounds stupid, but I installed Ubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows 10. Everything worked fine until I tried to login using the password I had provided.

It does not let me in. At first, I though that I had the wrong password. But then I tried changing my password using Ubuntu recovery in the boot menu. To be sure I didn't type the wrong password, I use 123456789 from my numeric pad. Because I was also afraid this could be a keyboard region issue. I still can't login with those simple numbers.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:** I tried solutions proposed in another post on login loop. Doing `ls -lA` did not work for me. However, in `/var/log`, I found `Couldn't open module nvidia" and "Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)`.

Is this the answer? And what is the solution. `dpkg-reconfigure`... command from other post did not work.

Comment: Do you see the dots (letter replacements) while you're typing, i.e. is the keyboard recognized properly? Do you see the accessibility tools icon (circle with human shape inside) on the login screen? If so, you could try entering the password with an on-screen keyboard. You also said you entered your numerical password with the numpad - are you sure NumLock was on at that time then? Next thing you could try is pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and trying to login there by typing first your username and then your password (note that the password input is invisible there). You go back to GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Alright so I tried what you asked. I see the accessibility tools, and I also used the onscreen keyboard but it's still not working. Actually this time I did not receive a login error, but the screen quickly became black with some lines and then the login screen again. The black screen comes and goes so fast that I can't read but an [OK]..... I also tried to change my password as 'toor', just so it would be easy. I tried Ctrl+Alt+F1. I can login both as 'root' and 'thomas' with the same password! So it seems my password is correct but I still can't login.

Comment: To confirm you password, I'd suggest switching to a terminal (eg. ctrl+alt+f4) and logging in.  If you can login, your password is okay. I'd then `df -hi` (disk free; human output inc. inodes) as no free space in /home means working-files needed for gui to login can't be created. With a new install this is unlikely; but it takes seconds. Next could be graphics card... You didn't say what version of Ubuntu; if its 17.10 trying using X (default is Wayland) -- at login screen you should see a gear logo; change to X and enter details...

Comment: I followed your instructions. I also have more details to give you. I successfully logged in using ctrl+alt+f4 so the password is fine. Then I also tried df -fi, it gave me inode names with free space on all of them but /dev/sda1 (wich has 0) and "-"  character under iUse% for /dev/sda1. /home is not listed there. I installed Ubuntu 16. I have now more details. When I enter my password, a black screen pops up for 1 second, it reads "Starting Power Management Daemon", then back to login screen. When I restart Ubuntu, also a black screen reading "Reached Target Network is Online". Any idea?